# Vue js app returns 404 in github pages but works fine on localhost

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, github-pages

So I have a Vue Js based app that I have hosted on Github pages. But the problem is that webpage loads correctly on index url and other pages also load successfully but if you refresh the page it returns a 404.

The below image shows how the page looks while loading the website normally.
[image: normally loaded page]

But if you refresh the above page, it will return a 404.

[image: 404 error]

The source code of the app is available at : [Repository URL](https://github.com/ProjectSakura/download)

The app works perfectly fine on localhost though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you cannot access server side config files i think you ve 2 ways:

1. Create a 404.html file with the same content of your index.html file ( in the public folder )
2. Set the vue router to [hash mode](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#hash-mode)