# Vue.js app hosted on githubpages not working with custom domain

Tags: vue.js, github-pages

So i have a Vue.Js bassed app, on localhost it works great. When i host it on github-pages without custom domain it works aswell, but when i change custom domain it shows 404 error :

[image: errors]

I've checked dns via https://dnschecker.org both A Records and CNAME gets resolved.

Github pages also resolves my dns:

[image]

As mentioned in [this so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475556/vue-js-app-returns-404-in-github-pages-but-works-fine-on-localhost) i've created a 404.html file in public folder.

Repo link : [Github](https://github.com/JacekBujalski/motel)

Domain : https://www.amberkrynica.pl

Answer (score 1):

It seems that not all DNS servers can resolve your nameservers. https://dnschecker.org/#NS/www.amberpokoje.pl

My guess is that this may be a problem with your registrars DNS changes not getting picked up by big DNS providers.

If the domain is new, the new nameservers may take some time to pop-up everywhere.

If it's not a new domain, try to contact your provider to check with them if everything is working.

Comment: Dang I've put wrong domain, correct one is : https://www.amberkrynica.pl. Domain is not new, changed dns about 24h ago so it should be done by now

Comment: @JackB sorry for not answering before, I see that now your site is working, what was the issue? It may be useful for other people in the future

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, I solved setting the `publicPath` to `'./'`.